# Cross Domain URL in jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cross-domain, cross-domain-policy

I have made a very simple index.php code as following

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/httpGet.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile.js"></script>   

</head> 

<body>
 <input id="string" type="text"/>
 <input id="button" type= "button" value="Check" />

</body>
</html>
```

In this HTML code we get a number fro user and call httpgGet.js file.
And the httpGet.js is :

```
$('#button').click(function() {
        var string = $('#string').val();
    $.post('http://...../isprime.php',{number: string},function(data){
      alert(data);
            } 
     }
```

we send the user number to a isprime.php file where it checks if a user number is a prime number or not. When I say $.post('php/isprime.php',.....) it works very well, but when I want to call the isprime.php from another computer, it does not work.

I mean  $.post('192.168.1.1/test/isprime.php'....) gives me a not found error.

The file exists and I am able to run the code using direct call from browser. When I type in browser 192.168.1.1/test/isprime.php the file is reachable, but from the js file, it fails. Obviously, I can ping 192.168.1.1 too. I checked the code even with FireBug and no way thorough.

I searched a lot and came a cross that Browsers do not allow cross domain call (for security purpose, I guess), but I cannot find a solution to get rid of this problem. There are something about YQL (which is a query language and I don't know if I can use it or not). Also I saw something about cULR but I am not sure if that works too.

Kindly help. I really need it.
thank u very much.

Comment: first when using full URL use http:// scheme, and second: you have to enable [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) for your site

Comment: Hi @Akam and thanks for reply. I used http too and it failed. I am using a XAMPP web server on my second computer to play the role of server. Eventually, this php code will be hosted on an Android mobile device which is playing a web server such as PAW. Does enabling CORS help?

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious solution, in my opinion, would be to make the request on the server side where you do not have the cross-domain request restrictions using the cURL library (as you mentioned, yes it would work). Of course, you would need to have the cURL library installed on your server. The [PHP cURL manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) should have enough information to get you started.

Comment: Thank @Default, my problem is how to access the server and run a code there. Because cURL is a PhP library and PhP cannot be executed in mobile side. If I can access server to run PhP m problem is solved. I am a beginner so I may not know basics. Pls don't hesitate to tell me all basics.

Comment: Right, so if you make an AJAX request to some endpoint on your server (as you are already doing via jQuery#post), you can use cURL functions to make a cross domain request and then return the information you need back to the client. The functions you will want to look at are curl_init(), curl_setopt(), curl_exec(), and curl_close() (possibly curl_getinfo() as well). Hopefully that helps.